# Android junit - access custom shared preferences in ServiceTestCase

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context, junit3, servicetestcase

I want to get shared preferences in ServiceTestCase:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and do something like that:

```
int value = preferences.getInt("key", 0);
preferences.edit().putInt("key", ++value).commit();
int newValue = preferences.getInt("key", 0);
assertTrue(value != newValue);
```

However, this does not work.
Test simply fails.

I've tried with different contexts:

```
getContext();
```

and

```
getSystemContext();
```

and also

```
getContext().createPackageContext(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(), Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

and finally

```
getSystemContext().createPackageContext(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(), Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Or maybe it's impossible to get custom shared preferences file in ServiceTestCase?

What about achieving that in activity test class?

Comment: I have extensive tests [here](https://github.com/Utumno/AndroidHelpersTest/tree/master/src/gr/uoa/di/android/helpers/test). Have a look. Try with `getDefaultSharedPreferences`

Comment: I must use my custom shared preferences, because I store there my data, and have other app components registered on their change. I could switch to use default shared preferences, but is it necessary? And testing response to changes in custom preferences is impossible?

Comment: dunno :) Try to replicate one of my tests using your prefs. I use `getContext` inside AndroidTestCase IIRC